# Is default constructor generated?

Tags: java

In the following program the display method is not part of Student4 constructor. So, when the method display is called using the Student4 constructor object does a default constructor invokes the display method?

```
class Student4 {  
    int id;  
    String name;  

    Student4(int i,String n){  
        id = i;  
        name = n;  
    }

    void display() {
        System.out.println(id+" "+name);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Student4 s1 = new Student4(111,"Karan");
        Student4 s2 = new Student4(222,"Aryan");
        s1.display();
        s2.display();
   }
}
```

Comment: come again? unclear...

Comment: the answer depends on how someone interprets your english... try to rephrase and clean up the question

Answer (score 6):

> So, when the method display is called using the Student4 constructor
>   object does a default constructor invokes the display method?

No. There's no default constructor in your class since you *explicitly* declared your own *parameterized* constructor. A *default* constructor is a constructor that have no parameter.

Methods are never part of a *constructor*. The constructor is a special method that's used to set initial values for field variables. Constructors are there to create an *instance* of a class, so when an object is created, Java calls the constructor first.

Answer (score 1):

> So, when the method display is called using the Student4 constructor
>   object

You are not calling the `display` function using `the Student4 constructor`, but using the objects `s1` and `s2`, that you constructed using your custom constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Student4(int i,String n){  
    id = i;  
    name = n;  
    display();
 }
```

now, your display method is called in your custom constructor. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand , if you are not defining any explicit constructor then the default constructor will created. Here you have already declared a parameterized constructor, so here it will not create any default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Java creates default constructor itself if no constructor defined in class but if you defined parametrized constructor you have to create default constructor

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Student4 s1 = new Student4(111,"Karan");
        Student4 s2 = new Student4(222,"Aryan");
        s1.display();
        s2.display();

       // if you create default constructor it will give you compile time issue
       // The constructor Student4() is undefined
        Student4 s3 = new Student4();
   }
```

When you create any instance of class, attributes and methods are the part of your object so your object is responsible to call your method not constructor.